# Compute StateResponse for list of inputs

Tags: differential-equations, control-systems

How do I find the state response of a system for a list of inputs?  Simply writing an array in the place where the input enters as an argument of `StateResponse` doesn't seem to work, I only get the response corresponding to the first input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
StateResponse[
   StateSpaceModel[{{{-1, 0}, {0, -3}}, {{1}, {2}}}, 
    SamplingPeriod -> None, 
    SystemsModelLabels -> None], #, t] & /@ 
       {UnitStep[t], Sin[t], Cos[t]}

(*

{{E^-t (-1 + E^t) UnitStep[t], 
  2/3 E^(-3 t) (-1 + E^(3 t)) UnitStep[t]}, {-(1/2)
     E^-t (-1 + E^t Cos[t] - E^t Sin[t]), -(1/5)
     E^(-3 t) (-1 + E^(3 t) Cos[t] - 3 E^(3 t) Sin[t])}, {1/
   2 E^-t (-1 + E^t Cos[t] + E^t Sin[t]), 
  1/5 E^(-3 t) (-3 + 3 E^(3 t) Cos[t] + E^(3 t) Sin[t])}}

*)
```

Comment: Delightful. Thanks!